# Cloudformation: How to read file contents from s3 object and use the contents in cloudformation template as a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am currently writing an AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule cloudformation resource with a Fixed Response action.

I would like to store the html to be used in fixed response in an s3 file.

How do I read it from there using cloudformation, and use that string object as the value for "MessageBody"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `MessageBody` is expecting a string.

If you're willing to write some code, you could create an [AWS CloudFormation Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html), which is a Lambda function that is part of the template. When the template is created (or updated or deleted), it triggers the Custom Resource Lambda function. The Lambda function can return a value.

Therefore, the template could trigger the Custom Resource, and the Lambda function could read the contents of the file from S3. The function can then return that as a string. The `MessageBody` can then refer to the output of the Lambda function when defining the Listener.